# Why my dev-c++ "can't open output file"?

Tags: c++, windows, g++

When I re-complied a .cpp file after crashing, my compiler told me this.

g:/program files (x86)/dev-cpp/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file C:\Users\chanson\Desktop\quickSort.exe: Permission denied

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Compilation failed after 1.00 seconds with errors

My system is win8.1, compiler is TDM-GCC 4.8.1 64-bit Release. I think it's the problem of my OS, but how can I fix this problem? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually the "permission denied" is because an instance of your program is **still running**.

You can use Task Manager to kill it.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> to run Task Manager, go to tab "Processes", find your process, kill it, but *be careful*. :)

---

Practical tip:

If you use the *console subsystem* for your app, at least while developing, then you can just run it from the command line, and kill it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd>.

Comment: Reboot might be safer.

Comment: @John: it depends. if by accident one kills a crucial process then a reboot might be the thing. but even explorer can usually just be started up again (it's designed for that).

Comment: rebooting will "mask" the problem, you will never know what happened.

Comment: actually it really works when I killed the process in Process Explorer， but I can't find this process in the Task Manager of system. By the way, is there a way that kill the process automatically after the app crashed?