# Eclipse acting weird in Windows environment

Tags: c, eclipse, ide

I'm trying to set up Eclipse with C/C++ but it's been causing me problems and despite trying to find a solution most of the afternoon I'm stumped.

I have the main program set up on my Windows PC (originally installed for Java, but now with the C/C++ plugin) and then followed a video on youtube to install/set up the rest like GCC. I can now compile and run programs successfully within the IDE, but for some reason if there is a scanf() function in the program it gets executed first, even if there is a printf() function  before it.

I wrote this small program to test it:

```
int main(void) {
int amount;

printf("Enter amount: ");
scanf("%d", &amount);

printf("amount: %d", amount);

return (0);
}
```

When it runs, the program demands input first without executing the print statement. If you enter some input, it then prints `Enter amount: amount: value`.

I've been using Eclipse on my mac for a while and it's never caused me any problems...

Comment: This has nothing to do with Eclipse. It's all about buffering. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1716296/10077

Comment: I don't really understand this / how it applies to my particular problem. The program would run on my macbook, what's causing it to act up in Windows? Is it not set up properly? I also get this error message during compilation (only sometimes:

Comment: Sorry, this is the error message: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file C A Modern Approach.exe

Comment: Buffering may behave differently on different operating systems. The error message is probably due to the program still running while you're trying to compile it. Windows doesn't like that.

Comment: For example see http://stackoverflow.com/q/20439193/10077

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the quick reply, but I'm afraid I still don't know how to get around the problem. Does this mean I need to alter the code itself?

Comment: Did you read the first question I linked, and particularly the [first answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1716621/10077)?

Comment: Yes. I didn't understand all of it. I tried adding setbuf(stdout, NULL);

Comment: ... at the beginning of the program. But it didn't make a difference.

Comment: How about adding `fflush(stdout);` after the `printf`?

Comment: Nope, that doesn't seem to be doing anything either.

Comment: Update your question to add (not replace) your modified code. I'll take a look.

Comment: Ok, I restarted Eclipse and then tried it again and it worked using setbuf(stdout, NULL); and fflush(stdout);. So that seems to have solved the main problem, thank you! Does this mean that I have to include the statement at the beginning of all function then? Also, is there a way to stop the error message during compilation from reappearing all the time? (When it appears, the program doesn't compile properly and I have to restart Eclipse).

Comment: @Daifel if you execute your original program outside of Eclipse do you have the same problem? I ran it in GDB in Windows, but without Eclipse, and it works fine.

Comment: You should need only the `setbuf` call or the `fflush`, not both. As for the error message, you just need to make sure your program is terminated before you recompile. In Eclipse, the console should have a red square when your program is running. If you click that, it should kill your program. But I'm not sure why it wouldn't just exit normally.

Comment: So making sure the program terminates is stopping the error. If I accidentally try to compile while it's still running I basically have to restart Eclipse though. Thanks so much for your help anyway, I can get back to actually learning some programming tomorrow :D

Comment: @TRKemp sorry just noticed your post. I tried the original program in command prompt and it worked fine.